# What is a good Amazon S3 client?

Tags: software-recommendation

I've been using the [Amazon S3 Management console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home) to browse my S3 files. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be able to sort files (in a given bucket) by anything other than whatever its default is (which seems to be by name). I'd like a nice GUI client for seeing these files which will let me sort them by date, so the newest will appear on top.

UPDATE: I'd also like it if the client could do a text search within a bucket ... but I suspect that this is wishful thinking.

Comment: I just gave http://www.crossftp.com/ a try and it worked like a champ. I was able to sort files by date and drag/drop download multiple files.

Comment: I'm on 18.04, QT S3 Browser is perfect: https://snapcraft.io/qts3browser

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**DragonDisk** is a decent Amazon S3 GUI client.(http://www.s3-client.com/) They have debian packages for ubuntu.
[image]

Comment: Maybe you can provide more information about Dragondisk, why is it decent (in your opinion) also how does its functionality answer the Ops specific requirements.

Comment: http://www.dragondisk.com/ is dead today

Comment: dragondisk.com is back online -- though it hasn't been updated in years it still works

Comment: Hmm. Seems like it still works, but it seems like AWS does not like to work with it anymore ...
<Error>
 <Code>InvalidRequest</Code>
 <Message>The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.</Message>

Comment: Can't comment on the dragon disk answer due to rep but it looks like the developer is planning on releasing a [new version that will support AWS V4 authentication](https://github.com/tonyp13/DragonDisk/issues/4).

Comment: It works fine but for some newer regions you might get error accessing the data courtesy this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533245/the-authorization-mechanism-you-have-provided-is-not-supported-please-use-aws4

Comment: Seems like the DragonDisk project is abandoned.

Comment: DragonDisk hasn't worked on Ubuntu for a while now and the project looks like it's been abandoned by the developer.

Answer (score 20):

Not a GUI but I went with `s3cmd`:

```
 sudo apt-get -qq install s3cmd
```

On its first run it asks for your credentials, i.e:

- access key
- secret key
- [region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.RegionsAndAvailabilityZones.html) (I went for 'eu-west-1')

and creates a `~/.s3cfg` where it stores all the things.

On success you can:

- list all your buckets by

  ```
    s3cmd ls
  ```
- list the content of a bucket by

  ```
    s3cmd ls s3://bucket-name
  ```
- fetch a file by

  ```
    s3cmd get s3://bucket-name/filename.txt
  ```
- upload a file into a bucket by

  ```
    s3cmd put LOCAL_FILE s3://BUCKET[/PREFIX]
  ```

For further information of the command look into:

```
man s3cmd
```

or read the [online version of the manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/s3cmd).

Comment: Although not being a GUI, I find this one to be the most acceptable of all :) Thanks!

Comment: what is the point of using this if its not a GUI, You could simply use aws cli if we want a command line interface: 
`$ aws s3 ls `

Comment: @Mohan Feel free to add aws cli as its answer here1.

Answer (score 14):

You have [`s3fs-c`](https://github.com/tongwang/s3fs-c). It's a [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) interface to S3. It'll take a little bit of work getting it up and running, but unlike the other two suggestions, it'll be transparent and act like any other kind of drive. You can save files right to S3. You'll be able to open up an S3 bucket and browse the files in any Linux Utility (ex. Gimp, Libre Office, etc).

In order to use `s3fs-c`, you'll have to compile it, and the configure it. You can find the instructions in the [INSTALL file](https://github.com/tongwang/s3fs-c/blob/master/INSTALL).

You'll need to install `build-essentials`, `libcurl4-openssl-dev`, `automake`, `pkg-config`, `libxml2-dev` and `libfuse-dev` to build it.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essentials libcurl4-openssl-dev pkg-config libxml2-dev libfuse-dev automake
```

then a simple `./configure`, `make` and `sudo make install` should get the build/install job done.

Comment: Note that by now (Dec 2014) [`s3fs-c`](https://github.com/tongwang/s3fs-c) is significantly behind [`s3fs`](https://code.google.com/p/s3fs/) (from which it was forked). `s3fs-c` does not support uid or gid, so I went with `s3fs` 1.74.

Comment: s3fs seems also to be available via apt-get in Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 8):

Free version of CrossFTP has S3 support and seems to do the job: http://www.crossftp.com Screenshot is from their website. The free version looks the same.

[image: CrossFTP]

Comment: It works for me, but the free version doesn't allow you to set permissions for files you've uploaded. http://www.crossftp.com/features.htm

Comment: Don't bother. CrossFTP doesn't work in the newest version (20.04)

Comment: @DaveKincaid - it requires Java to be installed (it doesn't come with Java bundled and uses `Recommends` in the deb package to require Java, which might not get it installed - depending on what you use to install it), but if you have that, it works fine on my 20.10 installation.

Comment: Incredibly (given it's Java, linux, and a GUI tool) it works for me on VERSION="22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
.

Answer (score 8):

### 2023 Follow-Up

- https://github.com/rclone/rclone : works nearly everywhere , e.g. self hosted minio
- https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse : works as usual with "all" backends
- https://github.com/minio/mc : works as well with most implementations

### self-signed certs might become tricky , but you could always use socat to circumvent this

- dragon-disk ( http://www.s3-client.com/download-s3-compatible-cloud-client.html ) : deb too old for current ubuntu ( unmet dependencies), binary archive is 386 only and fails on libQtXml.so.4 ( not installable from packages )
- https://github.com/cloudlena/s3manager → did not work with filebase
- crossFTP : did not follow ssl-redirects , did not offer ssl for custom endpoint
- OFFLINE: https://www.s3fox.net/ is now a casino site

Comment: Thank you for the write up. It seems like there is a lot of outdated info out there.

Comment: s3fs was the way to go for me - FS integration so can use terminal or Files to view

Answer (score 3):

You can also try [minio client](https://github.com/minio/mc) aka mc. `mc` is written in Golang and released under Apache license v2.

`mc` implements following commands

```
  ls        List files and folders.
  mb        Make a bucket or folder.
  cat       Display contents of a file.
  pipe      Write contents of stdin to one or more targets. When no target is specified, it writes to stdout.
  share     Generate URL for sharing.
  cp        Copy one or more objects to a target.
  mirror    Mirror folders recursively from a single source to many destinations.
  diff      Compute differences between two folders.
  rm        Remove file or bucket [WARNING: Use with care].
  access    Manage bucket access permissions.
  session   Manage saved sessions of cp and mirror operations.
  config    Manage configuration file.
  update    Check for a new software update.
  version   Print version.
```

Each command is self documented with examples, you just have to type

`mc <command> --help`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the free version of [Yarkon](http://yarkons3.com). It is an HTML based S3 browser.

Answer (score 1):

- https://github.com/kahing/goofys

> a high-performance, POSIX-ish Amazon S3 file system written in Go

- https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse

> FUSE-based file system backed by Amazon S3

Comment: I second that, though I recommend s3fs-fuse (available from Ubuntu official repo: `sudo apt install s3fs`). goofys has issues handling large files and can get stuck and freeze your file ops and mount. Otherwise, they both work the same: use the command to mount your bucket and use your favorite file browser. Example with s3fs: `s3fs mybucket ~/mnt -o use_path_request_style,url=https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com,profile=myprofile; xdg-open ~/mnt`. s3fs doesn't auto detect the region like goofys does and so you have to specify the full URL if you aren't using `us-east-1`.